# Notation for describing half-planes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation

In a 3D space, if I want to describe a half-plane of the plane $X=Y$ where $Z\geq{X}$, is there some concise notation for that?

Also, what is the notation for saying a point $P$ is on that half-plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a special notation for that. You can call it $H$ for "half", i.e. you can just say "Let $H=\{(X,Y,Z)\in\mathbb{R}\mid X=Y,Z\geq X\}$". Usually if $P$ is a point on $H$, you just say $P\in H$. Do you need more specific notation?

Comment: Nope, that does the trick - it's clear and gets the English out of it. I wasn't sure if there was a special notation. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any preference of $X=Y,Z\geq{X}$ vs. $X=Y,Z\geq{Y}$, or is it pretty arbitrary?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter, because $X=Y$ anyway.